# PrestaShop - Overriding module CSS files

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Im using Prestashop 1.6.0.9 and a module called agilemultipleseller.

Basically it turns your shop into a multi vendor store.

There are 2 CSS files that the module inserts that i need to override.

I cant take the reference to the CSS out of the module file as they are encoded.

The module structure is as follows:

```
/module/agilemultipleseller/css/agileglobal.css
/module/agilemultipleseller/css/agilemultipleseller.css
```

I have tried overriding the CSS files by placing my own in the following location

```
/themes/my_theme/modules/agilemultipleseller/css/agileglobal.css
```

Could anyone with knowlegde give me a pointer or 2.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the module is designed with overrides support the paths should be:

```
/themes/my_theme/css/modules/agilemultipleseller/agileglobal.css
/themes/my_theme/css/modules/agilemultipleseller/agilemultipleseller.css
```

Comment: How do i know if the module is designed with overrides support?

Comment: Just place files at the specified locations and see if they are used instead of the original ones.

Comment: It depends on the module's support. Another option is to place the css file under `<theme's dir>/css/autoload` directory.